# MVC custom validation on partial view

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, partial-views, unobtrusive-validation

I have 2 partial view.
Edit Page has columns var1, var2, var3.
Edit Section has columns varA, varB, var2, var3.

```
<div id="page-property" style="display:none;">
@Html.Partial("EditPage", new xxx.Domain.Entities.Page())
</div>
<div id="section-property" style="display:none">
@Html.Partial("EditSection", new xxx.Domain.Entities.Section())
</div>
```

First custom client validation test on var2 and var3 (both partial view):
EditPage custom validation show the error message when var2 = var3.
EditSection custom validation doesn't show the error message when var2 = var3.

Second custom client validation test on EditPage (var1, var2) and EditSection (varA, varB):
EditPage custom validation shows the error message when var1 = var2.
EditSection custom validation shows the error message when varA = varB.

```
// The unlike function
$.validator.addMethod(
    'unlike',
   function (value, element, params) {
       console.debug(element);
       if (!this.optional(element)) {
           var otherProperty = $('#' + params.otherproperty)
           return (otherProperty.val() != value);
       }
       return true;
   });

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
    'unlike', ['otherproperty', 'otherpropertyname'], function (options) {
        var params = {
            otherproperty: options.params.otherproperty,
            otherpropertyname: options.params.otherpropertyname
        };
        options.rules['unlike'] = params;
        options.messages['unlike'] = options.message;
    });
```

It looks like the second partial view validation not working due to the column name for both partial view are the same. Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think this is a bad design in your classes I think you can have a base class

```
public class baseclass
{
var2,var3}

public class page
{

public baseclass base{get;set;}
var 1
}

public class section{
vara,varb,
public baseclass base{get;set;}
}
```

and then on your views you will need to use an

```
editorFor(x=>x.base, Model.base)
```

and your editor will contain the class as normal.

As such you will preserve the validations

Comment: I am using EF for Page and Section table. The default validation is working fine for Page and Section with the same column name however the custom validation that I built has problem with it. I prefer focusing on the issue instead of changing the EF structure.

Comment: @Kenny: Your design is against the single responsibility of your class what would happen if I need Var1 of Page to be an int and var1 of section to be a datetime? in this case there would be a conflict and I am sure if you are talking of EF then the database has some flaw. Did you POCO your classes before or this is a legacy system using EF? Regards